# Hibernate HQL double inner join

Tags: hibernate, hql, inner-join

I try to launch this HQL query :

```
select elt.id from Delivery as dly  
    inner join  dly.programs as pgm
    inner join pgm.elements as elt
where dly=:deliveryid
```

I catch this exception :
ORA-01427: sous-interrogation ramenant un enregistrement de plus d'une ligne

What's wrong with my query ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select elt.id from Delivery as dly  
inner join FETCH dly.programs as pgm
inner join FETCH pgm.elements as elt
where dly=:deliveryid
```

If programs is an entity, but if programs is a collection you can't do a JOIN between programs and elements

Please change question title, you use INNER JOIN in your query not LEFT JOIN